# limit of $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}((x+1)^a - x^a)$

Tags: calculus

> Hello everybody, i couldn't figure out how to demonstrate this equation without L'Hopital i wonder if its possible.

$a \in (0,1)$
$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}((x+1)^a - x^a) = 0$

Comment: I'd use MVT.${}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)
$$0\leq x^a(1+\frac1x)^a-x^a\leq x^a\left(1+\dfrac{a}{x}\right)-x^a\to0$$
as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

By applying a [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition), as $u \to 0$, one gets
$$
\left( 1+u\right)^a=1+au+o(u)
$$ Then one may write, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
(x+1)^a - x^a=x^a \left[\left(1+\frac 1x\right)^a-1 \right]=x^a \left[\left(1+\frac {a}x+o\left(\frac1x \right)\right)-1 \right]=ax^{a-1}+o\left(x^{a-1} \right)
$$ which tends to $0$ since $a \in (0,1)$.